# How to change the background of the undo button in the snack bar

Tags: android, undo, android-snackbar

I'm unable to change the background of SnackBar. It's like a normal button, I want only a coloured `Undo` text with button functionality. How can I implement this?

SwipeToDelteCallBack.java

```
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        adapter.dismissjob(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView.getRootView(),"Deleted", LENGTH_LONG).setAction(R.string.SnackUndo, new Remove_job_recycle_adapter.UndoListener(position));

View snackbarview = snackbar.getView();
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.GREEN);
TextView snackbartextview = snackbarview.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);

snackbar.show();
```

Remove_job_Recycle_adapter.java

```
public static class UndoListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        int pos;
        public UndoListener(int pos){
        this.pos = pos;
        }
 @SuppressLint({"ResourceAsColor", "Range"})
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remove_job_recycleList.add(pos, data);

            SwipeToDeleteCallback.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(v,"Restored",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View snackbar1View = snackbar1.getView();
            TextView textView = snackbar1View.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            snackbar1View.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);
            snackbar1.show();
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVr9F.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView.getRootView(),"Deleted", LENGTH_LONG).setAction(R.string.SnackUndo, new Remove_job_recycle_adapter.UndoListener(position)).setActionTextColor(Color.GREEN);

snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the background from the view that holds the `undo` action, or set it to transparent like so:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```